# yarn install or yarn run build showing exit code 1 for my next js website

Tags: reactjs, npm, next.js, yarnpkg

Showing this error in my terminal

```
warning "next-optimized-images > file-loader@3.0.1" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@^4.0.0".
warning "next-optimized-images > raw-loader@2.0.0" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@^4.3.0".
warning "next-optimized-images > url-loader@1.1.2" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@^3.0.0 || ^4.0.0".
warning " > react-ga@3.3.0" has unmet peer dependency "prop-types@^15.6.0".
warning "theme-ui > @theme-ui/mdx > @mdx-js/react@1.6.22" has incorrect peer dependency "react@^16.13.1 || ^17.0.0".
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "lassi",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "serve": "next start",
    "export": "next export",
    "postbuild": "next-sitemap"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "framer-motion": "^2.7.5",
    "globby": "^11.0.0",
    "isomorphic-unfetch": "^3.0.0",
    "next": "9.5.3",
    "next-compose-plugins": "^2.2.0",
    "next-optimized-images": "^2.5.4",
    "prettier": "^2.1.2",
    "rc-drawer": "^4.1.0",
    "react": "16.13.0",
    "react-custom-scrollbars": "^4.2.1",
    "react-dom": "16.13.0",
    "react-ga": "^3.1.2",
    "react-icons": "^3.10.0",
    "react-modal-video": "1.2.6",
    "react-multi-carousel": "^2.5.5",
    "react-scroll": "^1.8.0",
    "react-stickynode": "^3.0.3",
    "theme-ui": "^0.3.1",
    "typeface-dm-sans": "^1.1.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "imagemin-mozjpeg": "^9.0.0",
    "imagemin-optipng": "^8.0.0",
    "imagemin-svgo": "^8.0.0",
    "next-sitemap": "^1.2.4"
  },
  "engines": {
    "npm": ">=8.7.0"
  },
  "overrides": {
    "react": "$react"
  }
}
```

Before the website was running well in localhost but not able to run build in next js. After I upgraded my npm and node js to
npm: '8.6.0',
node: '20.10.0',
Now I am not able to run it in my localhost as well